# How to argument handle multiple arguments of the same type

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I have this program about a neural network that runs like this:

> ./FOO --net net.tsv --label label.tsv --out out.txt

Basically, net.tsv contains the edges of the net, label.tsv the active nodes of the net

It has an argument handler that processes the command line, basically a cycle that takes each --command and a switchcase that handles every type

Now I have to implement a multi category version, something like:

> ./FOO --net net.tsv --label label.tsv --out out.txt --cat cat1.tsv ...
>   catN.tsv

Where cat1...catN contains the node indexes for every category

The program is already made but I can't find an efficient way to handle the arguments

The only thing I thought of is handling it like this:

> ./FOO --net net.tsv --label label.tsv --out out.txt --cat cat1.tsv
>   --cat cat2.tsv --cat etc...

And everytime the switch case finds a --cat, it puts the address of catX.tsv into a std::vector or something like that

Does someone know a more efficient way?

Comment: You've got the right idea. If you are handling multiple arguments for `--cat` then you don't need to specify another flag, just do `--cat file1 file2 file3` etc and store them into a `std::vector` when parsing the command line.

Comment: actually, it seems that the argument handler could only accept --cat file1 --cat file2 --cat file3, perhaps it's fust the way it is built

Comment: Command Line Parsers like [Boost Program Options](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.program_options) would absolutely support that type of input argument and store it into a vector.  Seems silly to specify the same flag for multiple arguments of the same type doesn't it?